# Bind Tables into one data frame

Tags: r

I have searched a couple of options, generally trying out various combinations on `cbind` to accomplish this. Essentially I would like to create a data frame that combines different pivot tables. into one data frame in order to export to csv/excel. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

EDIT: Essentially I am trying to learn the basics of creating a function that can wrap around multiple different pivot tables to create a data frame ready for export that will serve as a template to ad hoc reporting. The problem I am having is that the cbind product takes object B, which as a standalone will be a table with the dates as columns, and forces it into a long table, where the dates are transposed into rows.

dataframe:

```
State   FacilityName   Date
NY  Loew              June 2014
NY  Loew              June 2014
CA  Sunrise           May 2014
CA                    May 2014
```

code:

```
volume <- function() {
    df$missing = ifelse(is.na(df$FacilityName), "Missing", df$FacilityName)
    df = subset(df, df$missing == "Missing")
    x <- function(){
      a <- as.data.frame(table(df$FacilityName))
      b <- table(df$FacilityName, df$date)
      cbind(a, b[,1], b[2])
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: And your issue is that nothing is returned? If that is the case, you need a `return(x)` on the last line of your `volume` function. If your issue is that `x` cannot be found even after running the function, then you need to `assign` `x` to the global environment, which is not a recommended coding practice. Additionally, based on your code, what you are trying to do does not require functions. You are writing two functions with no inputs and only serve to abuse R's illogical/backward scoping rules.

Comment: You don't have enough closing brackets

Comment: My main problem is that the two tables, independently, create the views I want. It is when I try to bind them into one dataframe for export that they reshape and the Date columns turn into rows.

Comment: It would be helpful to get an example of the end result you are hoping to achieve.  As written, you are eliminating all of the rows with a non-NA value in FacilityName.

Comment: From prior comment, I think your issue is what happens when you try to column-bind a dataframe with a table.  R will first convert the table to a dataframe, which will treat all of the table entries as a column.  To get around this, either don't convert the other table to a dataframe, or use `cbind` to convert the second table to a matrix.

Answer (score 1):

When you give a factor to the table function, it uses the levels of the factor to build the table. So there's a nice way to obtain what you want by adding "Missing" to the levels of "FacilityName".

```
# loading data
ec <- read.csv(text=
'State, FacilityName, Date
NY,Loew,June 2014
NY,Loew,June 2014
CA,Sunrise,May 2014
CA,NA,May 2014', )

# Adding Missing to the possible levels of FacilityName
# note that we add it in front
new.levels <- c("Missing", levels(ec$FacilityName))
ec$FacilityName <- factor(ec$FacilityName, levels=new.levels)

# And replacing NAs by the new level "Missing"
ec$FacilityName[is.na(ec$FacilityName)] <- "Missing"
# the previous line would not have worked 
# if we had not added "Missing" explicitly to the levels


# table() uses the levels to generate the table
# the levels are displayed in order
# now there's a level "Missing" in first position
t <- table(ec$FacilityName, ec$Date)
```

You get:

```
> t   
            June 2014  May 2014
  Missing           0         1
   Loew             2         0
   Sunrise          0         1
```

You can add the total line like this (I don't think your code with `nrow` do what you say it does)

```
# adding total line
rbind(t, TOTAL=colSums(as.matrix(t)))

          June 2014  May 2014
Missing           0         1
 Loew             2         0
 Sunrise          0         1
TOTAL             2         2
```

At this point you have a matrix so you may want to pass it to `as.data.frame`.

This can be easily implemented into a separate function if you want to. No need to bind several tables after all :)

Comment: this is really great. Thanks for the help to thoroughly breaking it down for me.

Comment: this is really great. Thanks for the help to thoroughly breaking it down for me. One problem I am having though is that the second line, adding in the factor conversion is only catching "Missing" and not the FacilityName

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Check that `new.levels` contain what you expect it to. I assumed that FacilityName was already a factor, hence the need to "add" a new level. If it is not a factor (e.g. it is a character vector) then using `levels()` on it doesn't make sense. In this case you can build `new.levels` with `new.levels <- c("Missing", unique(ec$FacilityName))` for example. Hope it helps.

Comment: To explain the code in my previous comment: when you use the "levels" argument in the call to `factor`, only these precise levels are used (and any observation which is not in the levels vector will be set to NA). This is why it's important to specify correctly "new.levels". By default, if you just do `factor(something)` then the levels are `unique(something)` (which as the name suggests is just the "uniquified" vector where all values appear exactly once.

Comment: In fact, if `FacilityName` is not a factor but a character vector, you can just do  `ec$FacilityName[is.na(ec$FacilityName)] <- "Missing"` directly. If you _then_ do `factor(ec$FacilityName)`, "Missing" will be in the levels. Not at the first place though, which you seem to want. To specify the order of the levels, you have to do it as prescribed just above.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it seems I was trying to be cool and use a function to wrap everything in the hopes that it would be the beginning of learning to write flexible code. But, I did it the long way and ended up getting the result I wanted. While I will post the code that worked below, I am very interested in someone pointing me towards a better way to approach these kinds of problems, in order to learn better coding.

```
# Label the empty cells as Missing 
ec$missing = ifelse(is.na(ec$FacilityName), "Missing", ec$FacilityName)
# Subset the dataframe to just missing values    
df = subset(ec, ec$missing == "Missing")
# Create table that is a row of frequency by month for missing values
a <- table(df$missing, df$date)

# Reload dataframe to exclude Missing values
df = subset(ec, ec$missing != "Missing")
# Create table that shows frequency of observations for each facility by Month
b <- table(df$FacilityName, df$date)

# Create a Total row that can go at the bottom of the final data frame
Total <- nrow(ec)

# Bind all three objects
rbind(a,b,Total)
```

Here is an example of the final product I was looking for:

```
           May2014   June2014
Missing       2        0
Sunrise       0        0
Loew          1        2
Total         3        2
```